# when will Python 3 become the ROS standard

Tags: ros, rospy, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that someone has decided to [discontinue support for python 2 by 2020.](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/) Are there any plans to move rospy to use the python3 interpreter by default?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276663/when-will-python-3-become-the-ros-standard/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2017-11-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For ROS 1, it's not clear when Python 3 will be the default. You can read the discussion on Melodic target platforms here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/139

"ROS 2 supports Python 3 only." https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Migration-Guide

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on 2018-06-01**:
Thanks for that info! The fact that ROS doesn't support Python 3 in 2018 is honestly absolutely ridiculous.